# Transfer amount on blockchain larger than was sent from wallet

Tags: transactions

I sent some BTC from a hardware wallet last year.
The wallet shows a sent amount of 0.09302 BTC but when I look at the transaction id on blockchain.com it shows two amounts.

0.282 BTC unspent and 0.0924 BTC spent

Where has the 0.282 BTC come from was someone elses transaction somehow included with mine?

ea0be0433c3a0869aa62ff025abd33d5a400f51835f05c87f844d0e8158be0aa